# Reading a stream that may have non-ASCII characters

Tags: c#, stream, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have an application that reads string data in from a stream.  The string data is typically in English but on occasion it encounters something like 'Jalapeño' and the 'ñ' comes out as '?'.  In my implementation I'd prefer to read the stream contents into a byte array but I could get by reading the contents into a string.  Any idea what I can do to make this work right?

Current code is as follows:

```
byte[] data = new byte[len];  // len is known a priori
byte[] temp = new byte[2];
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input_stream);
int position = 0;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
  int c = sr.Read();
  temp = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(c);
  data[position] = temp[0];
  position++;
}
input_stream.Close();
sr.Close();
```

Comment: `int c` is actually holding a char or -1 for EOF, and for non-ASCII values it looks like you're throwing away half the value *and* fundamentally changing the encoding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to fill the contents into a byte-array, don't bother with the reader - it isn't helping you. Use just the stream:

```
byte[] data = new byte[len];
int read, offset = 0;
while(len > 0 &&
    (read = input_stream.Read(data, offset, len)) > 0)
{
    len -= read;
    offset += read;
}
if(len != 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, this was very helpful.  I am having a follow-up issue reproducing the string 'Jalapeño'.  When I do a `string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)` or `string s = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data)` neither of them works.  I get a StackOverflow exception (how appropriate!).  Would you have a recommendation on how to get back to a string from the stream while preserving the original characters?

Comment: @haxor what encoding is it stored with?

Comment: That's one of the challenges I have to deal with - I can only assume ASCII or UTF8.

Comment: do you think it would be better to go straight to a string and bypass the byte[] altogether?

Comment: @haxor can you perhaps post the byte sequence that is being so problematic? i.e. the byte-sequence for "Jalapeño" ?

Comment: StreamReader reads it fine, however you need to allow StreamReader to do the encoding, not try to do it yourself. The encoding for 'ñ' is 0xc391 in UTF8. If the file is stored as ASCII, the OS encoding will be used and potentially the wrong character be displayed. See my updated answer.

Comment: In the "ISO 8859-1" encoding 'ñ' is character 0xf1. In the "ISO-8859-7" 0xf1 is 'ρ'.

Comment: @WernerStrydom if it is truly ASCII, then the OS code-page is irrelevant; that only becomes an issue for ANSI

Comment: There is no 'ñ' in ASCII (aka 0x00 thru 0x7F). Any character higher than 0x7F is part of the "extended ASCII" and subject to the codepage.

Comment: So to answer the questions, we have to consider codepages and variations of UNICODE due to the fact that it references latin characters (aka 'ñ').

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the [encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx) to the StreamReader as in:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input_stream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

However, I understand that Encoding.UTF8 is used by default according to the documentation.

**Update**

The following reads 'Jalapeño' fine:

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var stream = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    var index = 0;
    var count = (int) stream.Length;
    bytes = new byte[count];
    while (count > 0)
    {
        int n = stream.Read(bytes, index, count);
        if (n == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();

        index += n;
        count -= n;
    }
}

// test
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

As does this:

```
byte[] bytes;
using (var stream = new FileStream("input.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
}

// test
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

From what I understand the 'ñ' character is represented as 0xc391 in the text when the text is stored with UTF encoding. When you only read a byte, you'll loose data.

I'd suggest reading the whole stream as a byte array (the first example) and then do the encoding. Or use StreamReader to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks - but the 'ñ' character still shows up as a '?' even when specifying Encoding.UTF8.

Comment: Be aware that Console.WriteLine may write "?" for a valid UNICODE character, like Chinese or Japanese.

Comment: Thanks Werner, the second example above "as does this" worked perfectly!